# How to achieve instant finality with substrate?

Tags: consensus, grandpa

Ideally, I would like to build a chain with Substrate but using Tendermint as the consensus engine.

The problem is that it's a lot of work to implement it correctly.

But what if I use `AURA` (round robin + delegated) and `GRANDPA` (propose, pre-commit, commit) with `sc_consensus::LongestChain` a custom `VotingRule` that triggers a vote for every block?
I would end up with something that behaves kind of close to Tendermint from a high-level point of view.

What would be the core difference? Would it scale as well as Tendermint? Is there some risk to do this?